# Export localstorage data from a http connection to a https connection IN a google extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, google-chrome-extension

I'm creating a google extension that takes data out of a database. This works, but only on a http connection (I don't care about security because it is for personal use). I save that data in 2 localstorages called `ls_question` and `ls_answer`. This works 100%, but when I go back to a https connection al that localstorage data is gone (probably because of security reasons).

So I want to export the localstorage from http connection to a https connection.

**I searched on google for a fix, i find some of them but they didn't work in a google chrome extention**

P.S. I tried to use cookies in javascript, i did it correct but only `ls_answers` ended as a cookie and `ls_questions` did not show up in the cookie list.
P.P.S. I can't use php in my code (becuse of the cookie)

Comment: What kind of server do you have ? If which techno ?

Comment: What do you mean? I dont use a server, because it is a extension

Comment: You are using à database, how do you access it ?